# Google Calendar API w/ Java - Get events only for the default calendar, ignoring the holidays

Tags: java, default, google-calendar-api

What I am trying to do is get a list of all the events in the default calendar only?  I don't want any other calendars' events included, i.e., holidays.

I am using the ".../feeds/username/default/full" and doing a query for all events from 1 month ago to forever.  I have two events that I have created but I get a feed with 25 entries.  My two events first and then 23 holidays.  I really don't them to be included at all but if them MUST be there, how do I detect them.  The only thing I can find is the eTag for my two events is different from the holiday ones.  But I can't just say get all the events from the first Etag I encounter because the default calendar may not have any events so the first one would be holidays.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a few lines of code using the latest version of the Google Calendar API.  All you need to do is pull the events for the primary calendar, as documented here:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#retrieving_events

The code you need is:

```
Events events = service.events().list("primary").execute();

while (true) {
  for (Event event : events.getItems()) {
    System.out.println(event.getSummary());
  }
  String pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
  if (pageToken != null && !pageToken.isEmpty()) {
    events = service.events().list("primary").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what version of the Calendar API you are using?  In v3 I am able to all my events without getting the holidays.  I added some more code examples, since the Google documentation is incorrect for connecting to the Calendar V3 API though Oauth2 for Java.

Use the code listed in the other post to loop though the Calendar events after the Oauth is setup and the Calendar is initialized.  You probably can, but do not need to declare the events API.  I just call it from the Calendar service(3).  Note the Calendar ID I have listed is "Primary."

```
Calendar service3 = new Calendar(transport, jsonFactory, accessProtectedResource);

com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar = service3.calendars().get("primary").execute();
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = service3.events().list("primary").execute();
```